# Divs with backgrounds for html/css

Tags: css, html

I already found a question similar but it didn't click.

Here is my code, I want to have two backgrounds. I know how to add two backgrounds but one background image needs to be in a specific place accomplished by using divs. My code may have the most simple flaw. Please be aware I am a newbie and trying to get into web development again from what little knowledge I already knew.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            <div id="currentpage">
                background-image: url(bgsource/contactpage.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            </div>
        }
        #currentpage{
            position: absolute;
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
            left:424px;
            top:134px;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:0px; 
        }
</style>
<?php include_once("general.php"); ?>
</head>
```

I may want to include that I have a general.php template that loads into every page, could that also affect the background from working?

Comment: You have a div tag in your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this. Because you cannot apply html tag inside css like you where mention in your question.

```
 <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #currentpage{
          position: absolute;
          width:auto; /* specify width */
          height:auto; /* specify height */
          left:424px;
          top:134px;
          margin-left:0px;
          margin-top:0px;
          background-image: url(bgsource/contactpage.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="currentpage"></div>
    </body>
```

And specify the `width` and `height` for `div` displaying the image. otherwise you will have a white background.

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo snap that's what I was missing omg ty ty ty ty ty ty ty ty ty  <33333333333333333333

Answer (score 1):

Your html and css are incorrect. See the corrections below

```
<style type="text/css">

        #currentpage{
            position: absolute;
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
            left:424px;
            top:134px;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:0px;
    background-image: url(bgsource/contactpage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    }
</style>
```

and html do this

```
<div id="currentpage"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, and @Hax_ as an explanation -- in css you don't put the actual markup, instead you put "selectors" which are ways to choose which dom elements (like div) a style is applied to.

Comment: now if your apply div style than used to this <div id="currentpage" style="background-image: url(bgsource/contactpage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
">Here your html code </div>

Answer (score 1):

```
       **change your css and html**

         <head>

           <style type="text/css">
        #currentpage{
            position: absolute;
            width:xx;
            height:xx;
            left:424px;
            top:134px;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:0px; 
            background-image: url(bgsource/contactpage.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    }
</style>


</head>
    <body>
   <div id="currentpage"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: The background still does not show up, just a white screen. I've been messing with this for a good hour now.

Comment: yea you should specify the width and height,like Ran said

Answer (score 0):

Yes.you can not use div tags inside your css page or within css script.

```
        background-image: url(bgsource/contactpage.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        left:424px;
        top:134px;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
```

use above code only your css page or within script tags but div tag not allow in css